Find all values a and b of the function $f(x)= \sum_{k=0}^{n}\sin(a_{k}x+b_{k})$
Find all values a and b of the function $f(x)= \sum_{k=0}^{n}\sin(a_{k}x+b_{k})$with the property that $\forall i_{1},i_{2}\in I: \exists{q\in \mathbb{Q}: a_{i_1}=a_{i_2}\times q }$ is never true.
And that $b_{k}<2\pi a_{k}$.
Now find all a and b by just knowing $f(x_{1})$ (some arbitrary but fix x value) and all derivatives at $x_{1}$
haw many derivatives are necessary to answer that in terms of n? is it always possible? and how?
So for $n=1$ it's pretty trivial, just take $x_{1}=0$ and tanke the first derivative now take the cosine of the arcsin of $f(0)$ decide the derivative at 0 by that and you have $a,b$ is just the arcsin of $f(0)$ (in case the derivative is in 0 is 0 take the second derivative). but for all higher n I'm clueless.
it might also be necessary to add the rule that  there are not allowed to be any extremes of to different k overlapping (which is not to much to ask since two different a already aren't rational to each other)

What would $I$ be?

I would just be the numbers that k can be
